# How do I detach, then re-attach to a kvm spice session?

Tags: kvm, qemu, spice

I have started a kvm session with typical qxl and spice options. The vm is running in the background via nohup.
I then started the spice client on the same host, using it to log in to the vm's gnome shell desktop.

Can I just close the spice window(click the x), and then relaunch the spice client later, picking up where I left off?

If not, is there a different client that allows this? I just want to 'pop in' once in a while and check the current desktop that is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the spice client just shows what a monitor would show. The machine continues to run in the background, even if you are not connected via spice. It also doesn't matter which spice client you are using.

Of course the qemu process must keep running If you kill that one, it's like "pressing the button".

Comment: Answered. Thank you chaos. I just went for it and it worked.